# Where can I find maintenance manuals for the A380?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, airbus-a380, electrical-system

My friend recently acquired an external green light from an A380. They are the only details i have from him. I tried hunting the internet for maintenance manuals, technical details, schematics, basically anything i can think of. Apart from a couple scam websites selling Haynes manuals, i came up with nothing.
Does anyone know the power requirements for the lights or, ideally, a document that lists aircraft details and specifications. I imagined that maintenance details will be available, but nothing came up.

Answer (score 2):

You’re going to be looking for the Airbus Illustrated Parts Catalog (IPC) for the A380 airplane.  It’s something I’m sure you can request from Airbus, but it’s gonna cost you.